# Find values where function is convex.

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given a function $f(x,y)=(sin(x)+2)y^2$  for $(x,y) ∈ R2$ where $x$ is periodic.

I am trying to find the values $(x,y)$ where the function is convex.

I need to use the Sylvester criterion to fin the values. I have tried using the Hessian matrix and find where the determinat is greater than 0 but I don't quite understand how to proceed from the matrix.

The Hessian Matrix I have acquired is:

H =\begin{pmatrix}
-y^2sen(x) & 2cos(x)y\\
2cos(x)y & 2(sin(x)+2)
\end{pmatrix}

I have tried calculating the $|a_{11}|$ and $|H|$ determinants and equaling them to $>0$. One of the solutions found is:
$x=2*\pi*n+\pi, y=0$ for $n ∈ Z$.

I don´t really know if this is or why would be a possible answer and if it were, how could I answer the original question with this information.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your outline seems reasonable, but where exactly are you stuck? Have you computed the Hessian? Have you applied Sylvester's criterion?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added a bit more context. I may not really understand what I am looking for since once I represent the function, I don't quite understand where the convexity fails.

Comment: Should $2 \cos x$ be $2 y \cos x$ instead?

Comment: @angryavian yes you are right, it was a mistake but I had it written correctly in my notebook.

Comment: x is a domain variable; sin is periodic but x is not.